# Faixa de valores para comparar

Tags: javascript, if, operadores

Quando eu Peço um valor aleatório no `Math.Random()` quero que ele diga se foi normal, desastre ou falhou mais não consigo fazer ele falar normal pois preciso que quando seja maior que 2 e menor que 19 ele fale falhou. Precisa ser roll1 > 2 e < 19.

```
if (roll1 == 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19){
    console.log(`FALHOU`);
  }
  if (roll1 == 20){
    console.log(`NORMAL`);
  }
  if (roll1 == 1){
    console.log(`DESASTRE`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Você deve usar os operadores de comparação `x < y` e `x > y`, ou se deseja que seja a partir do 2 até o 19 use os `x >= y` e `x <= y` na IF, a primeira IF poderia ser `if (roll1 >= 2 && roll1 <= 19){`, usando o && para checar se ambas condições estão corretas.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Teste o que é mais fácil primeiro, o que é valor único, então faça isso com o 1 e o 20, depois o que está dentro dessa faixa é o que sobrou, não precisa testar explicitamente, ele é o exceto, então ele já cai no `else` se não for qualquer um dos números que testou diferente.

E tome o cuidado para todas condições estarem vinculadas, o `else if` serve para isso, a execução vai cair apenas em um dos `if` ou `else`, é uma seleção do mais adequado, o primeiro que ele entrar nem tenta outros, o `else` sozinho garante que entrará ali se não entrar em nenhum `if` anterior. Ele é como se fosse um `else if (true)`.

Precisa ver se não não pode dar outro valores, eu imagino que não, já que o código indicava isso.

```js
var roll1 = 3;
if (roll1 == 1) {
    console.log(`DESASTRE`);
} else if (roll1 == 20) {
    console.log(`NORMAL`);
} else {
    console.log(`FALHOU`);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Select.js).

Se puder ter outros valores aí tem que mudar:

```js
var roll1 = 3;
if (roll1 == 1) {
    console.log(`DESASTRE`);
} else if (roll1 == 20) {
    console.log(`NORMAL`);
} else if (roll1 > 1 && roll1 < 20) {
    console.log(`FALHOU`);
} else {
    console.log(`Deu número inválido`);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Select2.js).